# How to authorize my API requests with django google-auth?

Tags: django, authentication, google-authentication, django-allauth, django-socialauth

I have implemented google-auth in my Django project, using *allauth*, and it works perfectly. After successful verification, I get some key from this view.

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.views import GoogleOAuth2Adapter
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView

class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
```

{
"key": "12b6e1696cdd73ddede1334f683003f63426f423"
}

At this point how can I authorize my other API requests by this key to identify a user on my server?  Or what else I need to do ?
How to use this key in my other requests ?

Comment: I am wondering if you have found an answer.